# Why array is accessible deep in the recursive stack while int type does not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a recursive function, and while deep in the recursive stack, I'm surprised that I'm still able to reference an array but not an int-type variable. Why is it so?

```
    def sumRootToLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        ans = 0
        def DFS(root, combination):
            if not root:
                return
            newComb = combination+str(root.val)
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                ans += int(newComb, 2) # ans not accessible
            DFS(root.left, newComb)
            DFS(root.right, newComb)
        DFS(root, "")
        return ans
```

```
        ...
        bin = []
        def DFS(root, combination):
            if not root:
                return
            newComb = combination+str(root.val)
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                bin.append(newComb) #array is accessible
            ...
```

Comment: How do you know whether these things are accessible or not?

Comment: @quamrana i know array is accessible because the code ran fine, while the code with ans does not.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. What about the code means that `"code with ans does not"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you change the object that `ans` represents but the object that `bin` represents does not change. If you modified the second piece of code to `bin = bin + [newComb]` you would get the same error.

You can add `nonlocal ans` to the top of the first `DFS` function to let the interpreter know that you intend to change the value of `ans` outside the current scope